# GraphQL query that excludes results where an array relationship is empty

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have this query (in Hasura in case that matters):

```
query MyQuery {
  records(distinct_on:[recordId],   where: { modelId: {_eq: "2f1f70b8-cb7b-487c-9e4c-ca03624ce926"}}) {
    recordId
    inboundEdges(where: {fromModelId: {_eq: "f0e19461-6d38-4148-8041-54eba6451293"}}) {
      fromRecord {
        property_path_values(where:{stringValue:{_eq:"2021-08-26"}}) {
          stringValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this result back:

```
{
  "data": {
    "records": [
      {
        "recordId": "2fbe37b1-78db-4b22-b713-2388cfb52597",
        "inboundEdges": [
          {
            "fromRecord": {
              "property_path_values": [
                {
                  "stringValue": "2021-08-26"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "fromRecord": {
              "property_path_values": [
                {
                  "stringValue": "2021-08-26"
                },
                {
                  "stringValue": "2021-08-26"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "recordId": "7b34e85d-f4e1-4099-89d9-02483128a6cd",
        "inboundEdges": [
          {
            "fromRecord": {
              "property_path_values": [
                {
                  "stringValue": "2021-08-26"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "recordId": "840f52e2-0f2e-4591-810d-19f9e8840a49",
        "inboundEdges": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I do not want the third result in the response, because it's `inboundEdges` array is empty.

What I am trying to say is: find me all `records` that have at least one `inboundEdge` with a `fromRecord` that has at least one `property_path_value` with a `stringValue` equal to `2021-08-26`.  I do not want to have to parse the response needing to exclude results with `inboundEdges === []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was confusing the selection set with the place to state the query.  The right way to do what I wanted is:

```
query MyQuery {
  records(where: {inboundEdges: {fromModelId: {_eq: "f0e19461-6d38-4148-8041-54eba6451293"}, fromRecord: {propertyPathValues: {stringValue: {_eq: "2021-08-26"}}}}, modelId: {_eq: "2f1f70b8-cb7b-487c-9e4c-ca03624ce926"}}) {
    recordId
  }
}
```

i.e. put the query in the where clause, like a normal person, not the selection set